# Java GUI app,server reads only first request

Tags: java, client-server

While making a simple Client-Server GUI app where upon the user's input dimensions of shapes are read and sent back to the server,where the method **drawShape** is invoked,after sending the initial request("CONNECT##" + NEW) and servers response with (DIM x,y),everything stops,client receives the (DIM x,y )prints ou ***"1:Draw point\n2:Draw circle\n3.Draw rectangle"***,and **THEN IT WILL NOT SEND BACK TO THE SERVER NO MATTER WHAT I TRY TO OUTPUT**,(I tried with a single word) and it did not work.

I really don't know what may be the issue,and I'm struggling with it for several days.
I parsed values,closed scanner,checked scanners,checked loops...
Why is PrintWriter refusing to send OutputStream response to the server?

This is the code:

```
public static final int TCP_PORT = 8000;

public SGPClientThread(Socket sock) throws IOException {
    this.sock = sock;

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()),1);
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())), true);

    start();
}

ETFCanvas can = new ETFCanvas(450, 500);

public void run() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Send new request by entering '<NEW>'");

    String option = "";
    option = scan.nextLine();
    out.println("CONNECT##" + option);

    String read = " ";
    try {
        read = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (read.startsWith("<DIM x,y>")) {
        System.out.println("1:Draw point\n2:Draw circle\n3.Draw rectangle");
        // SO FAR SO GOOD!
```

**> Following code is where the problem occurs,anything I try to print out,will not be 
sent to the server,it does not have to be this,you can simply try to send a
word or something simple,not working.**

```
        **int choice = scan.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Dimension and color of POINT:x1,y1,color");
            System.out.println("Enter X: ");
            x = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Y: ");
            y = scan.nextInt();
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Enter Color value: ETFCanvas.COLOR_RED;ETFCanvas.COLOR_BLUE;ETFCanvas.COLOR_GREEN");
                    color = scan.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid input ");
                }
                scan.nextLine(); // clears the buffer
            } while (color <= 0);
            scan.close();
            String iks = String.valueOf(x);
            String ipsilon = String.valueOf(y);
            String kolor = String.valueOf(color);
            out.println("<POINT x,y,c>##" + iks + "##" + ipsilon + "##" + kolor);
            break;**
```

> Blockquote

**And to keep it short I did not post the rest of the client thread it is just the Case 2 and 3 for drawing Circle and Rectangle,and closed Socket.**

Here is my Server Thread code;

```
    ETFCanvas can = new ETFCanvas(450, 500);

public ServerThread(Socket sock, int value) throws IOException {

    this.sock = sock;
    this.value = value;

    // oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    // ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()),1);
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())), true);
    start();

}

@Override
public void run() {

    String line = "";
    //
    try {
        line = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //
    if (line.startsWith("CONNECT##")) {

        System.out.println("User sent request " + sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + line);

        String[] content = line.split("##");
        req = content[1];
        if (req.equals("<NEW>")) {
            out.println("<DIM x,y>");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Bad request [" + sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + "]: " + line);
```

**> Till this part it is working like a charm,and then it will not read a clients
request for drawing**

```
    }
    if (line.startsWith("<POINT x,y,c>##")) {

        System.out.println("User sent request TRY" + sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + line);

        String[] dim = line.split("##");
        String dimX = dim[1];
        String dimY = dim[2];
        String dimC = dim[3];

        int x = Integer.parseInt(dimX);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(dimY);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(dimC);

        can.drawPoint(x, y, ETFCanvas.COLOR_RED);
    } else if (line.startsWith("<CIRCLE x,y,r,boja>##")) {

        String[] dim = line.split("##");
        String dimX = dim[1];
        String dimY = dim[2];
        String dimR = dim[3];
        String dimC = dim[4];

        int x = Integer.parseInt(dimX);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(dimY);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(dimR);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(dimC);

        can.drawCircle(x, y, r, ETFCanvas.COLOR_RED);
    } else if (line.startsWith("<RECTANGLE x,y,w,h,boja>##")) {

        String[] dim = line.split("##");
        String dimX = dim[1];
        String dimY = dim[2];
        String dimW = dim[3];
        String dimH = dim[4];
        String dimC = dim[5];

        int x = Integer.parseInt(dimX);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(dimY);
        int w = Integer.parseInt(dimW);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(dimH);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(dimC);
        can.drawRect(x, y, w, h, ETFCanvas.COLOR_RED);
        ;
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please consider crafting and posting a [mcve] version of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code you read the first line from input but you never read next line anywhere in your code.

You should use `while` loop to read lines, process them and repeat:

```
boolean shouldProceed = true;
while (shouldProceed) {
    line = in.readLine();
    if (line.contains(...)) {
        // do something
    } else if (line.comtains(...)) {
        // do something else
    } else {
        shouldProceed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,this solved the issue,I had to put my while loop before the first in.readLine,I was putting it after.Thank you.